# How to detect if an asmx web service is being called?

Tags: .net, iis, asmx

I have an existing asmx web service that calls internal business logic. I cannot change the asmx service to add any indicators.

How can I detect (using some external method, or checking IIS) if that particular web service is being called?

I know this is possible with WCF using a singleton model, but this particular service is asmx based.

Update: Just for clarity. I guess I'll end up creating a 2nd web service, when called it can check if 1st web service is executing, if not it calls the 1st web service and returns results, if its executing it will wait a while then retry. So how to find out if 1st web service is running from within 2nd web service process.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use firebug to debug the site. When enabled, it will show you which methods from which service are being called (and their load-time, but that's irrelevant here).

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, this should be programatically, without user intervention.